# Refresh element height and size on window refresh with directive

Tags: angularjs

At the moment, the following directive grabs the width and height of an element on page load. How do I get it to refresh it on window resize?

```
angular.module('adsomaApp')
  .directive('elementSize', function ($timeout) {
    return {
      restrict: 'A',
      link: function (scope, element, attrs) {
        element.ready(function () {
          var height, width;
          $timeout(function () {
            height = element[0].offsetHeight;
            width = element[0].offsetWidth;
            if (attrs.key) {
              scope[attrs.key] = {
                height: height,
                width: width
              };
              return;
            }

            scope.elementSize = {
              height: height,
              width: width
            };
          });
        });
      }
    };
  });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not clear what the purpose of the directive is (i.e what is `elementSize` used to, what is the purpose) but why not just hook into `$window` `resize`? Here a refactored version :

```js
.directive('elementSize', function($timeout, $window) {
  return {
    restrict: 'A',
    link: function(scope, element, attrs) {
      var height, width;
      var measure = function() {
        height = element[0].offsetHeight;
        width = element[0].offsetWidth;
        if (attrs.key) {
          scope[attrs.key] = {
            height: height,
            width: width
          };
        }
        scope.elementSize = {
          height: height,
          width: width
        };
        //log values
        console.log(scope.elementSize)
      }

      $timeout(function() {
        measure()
      });
      angular.element($window).bind('resize', function() {
        measure()
      })

    }
  };
});
```

Seems to work when I resize the panes -> **http://plnkr.co/edit/qOAQeWUYBcgeWgvEcBKk?p=preview**

But again, not sure if this really is what you have in mind.

Comment: Thanks this exactly what I needed